# Laravel 5.2 - Join through multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following tables:

```
User
    id

Suggestions_For
    id
    user_id
    suggested_account

Suggestions
    id

(User.id = Suggestions_For.user_id)
(Suggestions_For.suggested_account = Suggestions.id)
```

If I want to get all suggestions for user like this:
$user->suggestions()->count()

how can I do it? Is there way to define a relationship in my model that goes through multiple pivot tables to join a user to suggestions?

I've tried with:

```
public function suggestions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Suggestions', 'App\Suggestions_For', 'suggested_account', 'id');
}
```

but does not seems to work

Comment: This seems like a simple `manyToMany` relationship. Or am I wrong? It's been a while since I touched laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your relationship as `ManyToMany` using pivot table `suggestions_for` as

User Model

```
public function suggestions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Suggestions::class, 'suggestions_for', 'user_id')
}
```

Suggestions Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'suggestions_for', 'suggested_account ')
}
```

Comment: @ariel Give it a try first, On user object you can get related suggestions like `$user->suggestions()->get()` similarly on suggestion object you can get related users `$suggestion->users()->get()`. I have posted a many to many example using pivot table

Comment: I had, error is: Call to a member function get() on null, $user->suggestions() returns null

Comment: @ariel My bad i forgot to add `return`  before `$this->belongsToMany`

Comment: amazing, thank you!! correct code was: public function suggestions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Suggestions::class, 'suggestions_for', 'user_id', 'suggested_account')
}